# Handling errors properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn swift and I have hit a wall... I want to be able to switch the type of error i get back so I can do different things. It works fine in the .success but not in the .failure

```
 exporter.export(progressHandler: { (progress) in
            print(progress)
        }, completionHandler: { result in
switch result {
                case .success(let status):
                    switch status {
                    case .completed:
                        break
                                            
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    // I want to check what the error is 
                    // e.g. the debugger says its "cancelled"
                  
                 
                    break
            }
        })
}
```

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the type of error"? What are the possible error "types" that you might get? How was this Result created in the first place? Show more code.

Comment: what is type of error ? is it NSError ?

Comment: i just get Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Error' and 'String' in the debugger @jawadAli if i do an if statement with a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to *see* what happened, print the `error` object's `localizedDescription`.

```
 print(error.localizedDescription)
```

If you have a *decision* to make, cast to NSError and examine the `domain` and `code`. That is more reliable though not as user-friendly. Only actual testing will tell you what the possible values are.

```
let error = error as NSError
if error.domain == ... && error.code == ... {
```

You can work out the corresponding Swift `Error` type by looking in the *FoundationErrors.h* header file. Once you do, you can refine your `case` structure to filter the error type into its own `case`:

```
case .failure(let error as NextLevelSessionExporterError):
     // do something
case .failure(let error): 
     // do something else
```

Comment: is it safe to just an if statement on the localizedDescription string? Can this change depending on the device

Comment: No, it isn't safe. That's why I didn't say to do that. Please read my answer.

Comment: I have cast the error like this. let test = error as! NextLevelSessionExporterError.... test.description has "Cancelled".. is it ok to use this? The object only seems to have a description, self, hash, hashValue and localizedDescription now that i have casted it

Comment: If you know that this might be a NextLevelSessionExporterError then you should have a case that handles just that type of error. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Sorry but could you give me an example of how to do that. I was just using the second example from here https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevelSessionExporter#example I am not used to this syntax